# Installing a windows service through powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script which install a windows service and I want to convert it to a powershell script or command to do the same job.

I have been trying to use the New-Service cmdlet without much success

The batch script is given below:

```
cd %~dp0%
set SERVICE_NAME=ESL_SERVICE

IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    set PR_INSTALL=%~dp0prunsrv_32.exe
) ELSE (
    set PR_INSTALL=%~dp0prunsrv_64.exe
)

echo $PR_INSTALL

set PR_DESCRIPTION=ESL-Server
set PR_DISPLAYNAME=%SERVICE_NAME%
set PR_STARTUP=auto

set PR_CLASSPATH=server.jar
set PR_JVMOPTIONS="-Xmx1024M"

set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.Server
set PR_STARTMETHOD=main

set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPCLASS=at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.ServerServiceStarter
set PR_STOPMETHOD=stop

IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    prunsrv_32.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
) ELSE (
    prunsrv_64.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
)
```

This is what I have done so far..and the service gets installed but it does not start the sevice

```
$PR_CLASSPATH = "server.jar"
$PR_JVMOPTIONS = '"-Xmx1024M"'

$PR_STARTMODE = "jvm"
$PR_STARTCLASS = "at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.Server"
$PR_STARTMETHOD = "main"

$PR_STOPMODE = "jvm"
$PR_STOPCLASS = "at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.ServerServiceStarter"
$PR_STOPMETHOD = "stop"

New-Service -Name ESL_SERVICE -binaryPathName "C:\imagotag\server\prunsrv_64.exe //RS//ESL_SERVICE" -Description "ESL-Server" -DisplayName ESL_SERVICE -StartupType Auto
```

Comment: What are you having problems with? Show the powershell script you're trying to get working, this is not a code writing service and it is unlikely somebody will simply rewrite your script for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for code without showing any effort.

Comment: I have added the progress that I have made so far to the initial post..I did not post this before because it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the `Start-Service` command, after the `New-Service -Name ESL_SERVICE -binaryPathName ...` line?

```
Start-Service -Name ESL_SERVICE
```

`New-Service` only creates the service. The `-StartupType Automatic` will only start this after next reboot.

From `Get-Help New-Service -full`:

> -StartupType Automatic: The service is to be started (or was started) by the operating system, at system start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys but I finally managed to figure it out..using a different way

I managed to write the procrun service by using command line parameters instead of variables (the batch script used variables to run the procrun service) and now its installing and working fine.

```
.\prunsrv_64.exe //IS//ESL_SERVICE --Description ESL-Server --DisplayName ESL_SERVICE --Startup auto --Classpath server.jar ++JvmOptions '"-Xmx1024M"' --StartMode jvm --StartClass at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.Server --StartMethod main --StopMode jvm --StopClass at.mrdevelopment.esl.server.ServerServiceStarter --StopMethod stop --LogPath $LOG_PATH

Start-Service -Name ESL_SERVICE
```